# I accidently changed my display name

Tags: support

I accidently renamed my "display name".

so is there any way i can revert to old nme within 30 days, when i googled it,

I found this : [Revert a display name change within 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45208/revert-a-display-name-change-within-24-hours)

so if any moderators revert to my old name, i will be thankfull to them.

Comment: You want it "Baby in Magento" or "Baby in Magento 2" ?

Comment: Awesome Marius, you are express , I need "Baby in Magento".....

Comment: one more thing...you want it changed for this website only, or for all the stackexchange network? I see you take part in 8 communities

Comment: only for website enough boss......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. Please be more careful next time.

Comment: Sure, I always follow your words : - )